# how to store string with hexadecimal character to environment variable and then retrieve in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, environment-variables

How can I save a string with hexadecimal values to environment variable and later retrieve it in ruby?

Currently, when I retrieve it using `ENV[]` it will return with slashes escaped. So it retrieves like `"\\x12\\x33"`. How can I make it so that when the environment variable is retrived from ruby then it returns the same exact string `"\x12\x33"`.

Suppose I have a string with hexadecimal characters such as

```
s = "\x12\x33"
```

I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is an issue. Console will output it escaped automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i solved this by first writing the binary to file and then reading it.

Writing

```
data = "\x12\x33"

File.open("data.bz2", "wb") do |f|
  f.write(data)
end
```

Reading

```
file = File.open("data.bz2", "rb")
contents = file.read
print contents
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TEST='\x34\x33' ruby -e "
  puts ENV['TEST'].split('\\x')[1..-1].map(&:to_i).map(&:chr)"
#⇒ "
#  !
```